# Entity Framework, having a navigation property connected to two (or more?) scalar properties

Tags: entity-framework

Having a little trouble with entity framework and couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I am trying to set up a database/model for a volleyball team.

```
public class Match
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime GameTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Team HTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team ATeam { get; set; }
    public String HScore { get; set; }
    public String AScore { get; set; }
}
public class Team
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

A team can be either Away or Home team, so for Team.Matches I want it to be a list where the team has been either. Can this be done with entity framework?
When I do it like above there is a new column in Match that stores team_id, but it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to get `Team.Matches` to populate based on two possible relationships.

Another way to think about it from a database point of view, your Match table has a many-to-many relationship to Team, you are just limiting the Match to only have 2 Teams, one of which is a Home team.

Consider the following:

```
public class Match
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public DateTime GameTime { get; set; }
  public virtual List<MatchTeam> MatchTeams { get; set; }
}

public class MatchTeam
{
  public virtual Match Match { get; set; }
  public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
  public bool IsHomeTeam { get; set; }
  public string Score { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual List<MatchTeam> MatchTeams { get; set; }
}
```

When referencing there would be an in-between step for match/team info (IsHomeTeam, Score) before going to the Match/Team.

```
string homeTeamScore = string.Format("Team {0} scored {1}",
  match.MatchTeams.First(mt => mt.IsHomeTeam).Team.Name,
  match.MatchTeams.First(mt => mt.IsHomeTeam).Score
);
```

You could add a HomeTeam property and tell EF to ignore it as follows:

```
public Team HomeTeam
{
  get
  {
    return MatchTeams.FirstOrDefault(mt => mt.IsHomeTeam);
  }
}
```

I'll leave the `set` for you to play with, let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: This was a bit more than I could understand.
I finally went with a viewmodel containing a Team and an array of Matches, in the code getting the team that match and the match where team.id is matching on either home or away team.